# Custom LSTM cell implementation

Tags: pytorch, lstm

Shoutout to all Pytorch core developers!

I would like to implement a custom version of the typical LSTM cell as it is implemented in Pytorch, say, change one of the activation functions at a gate. For this, I would like to see how the LSTM is implemented in Pytorch at the moment. I can find some code [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py), but unfortunately, I cannot find the exact LSTM computations there, including the implementation of the gate formulas as they are also specified in the docstrings.

Related posts can for example be found [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-modify-lstm/12004/12), but all they delivered me is that nobody has found the LSTM cell code in github.

Where is the LSTM cell implemented in the Pytorch Github exactly?

Comment: That is the code that computes LSTM outputs https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e9ef087d2d12051341db485c8ac64ea64649823d/benchmarks/fastrnns/cells.py#L25

Comment: Thanks so much, Mihail! Can I ask: Can you explain how this code is used by the class LSTMCell in https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py ? I can see that in line 941, "lstm_cell", but when looking at _VF, I don't really understand how this is imported from the source that you pointed to.